# Pandas loc - filter values appear in list in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame looks like this:
[image: Dataframe]

Where `text` is a list of words.
Also, I have a `words` list which is also consists fully by words.
I'm tring to filter out rows that the `text` field contain words in `words` by iterating through `words` using `loc`.

However, when I tried to write the following:

```py
for word in words:
    df.loc[word in df['text']]
```

An error returned. I've also tried to use the `isin()` fuction, but strings don't have this feature.
What should I do?

Comment: Can you post here a reproducible subset of your dataframe and the list `words`?

Comment: also, a sample of desired output required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this if you want to iterate over the `words` list:

```
columns = df.columns
df['text_joined'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x:' '.join(x))
for word in words:
  df_sub = df.loc[df['text_joined'].str.contains(word),columns]
```

else, please try this if you want to subset the data whose texts contains any word in the list `words`

```
import numpy as np
def find_word(text_ls):
  for text in text_ls:
    if text in words:
      return 1
  return np.nan

df['text_id'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x:find_word(x))
df_sub = df.dropna(subset=['text_id']).drop(columns=['text_id'])
```